# this.<name> is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This question was answered a lot but I have tried them all with no success. I tried binding the function but it still gives me this error:

`_this3.toggleDrawer is not a function`

Code:

```
class DrawerContent extends Component {
  toggleDrawer() {
    this.context.drawer.toggle()
  }
  _renderHeader(section) {
    if (section.content.length === 0) {
       var sectionID = section.title.match(/\d/g).join("")
       return(
         <View>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
             NavigationActions.movie_grid({dataID: sectionID})
             this.toggleDrawer()
           }}>
             <Text style={{color: "#000", padding: 15}}>{section.title.replace(/[0-9]|,/g, '')}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
       )
    } else {
      return(
        <View>
          <Text style={{color: "#000", padding: 15}}>{section.title.replace(/[0-9]|,/g, '')}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to bind `this` explicitly while you invoke your function to be like this: `this.toggleDrawer().bind(this)`.

Comment: @BasimHennawi I did try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included all of your code here, but my guess is you aren't binding `_renderHeader()`. I assume this is being used in a `ListView`, so it should look something like this:

```
<ListView
    renderHeader={this._renderHeader.bind(this)}
    ... />
```

That binds `this` within `_renderHeader`, which can then further bind `this` properly in your other functions.

Comment: I sadly can't show the entire source code but the renderHeader function is for an accordion not the ListView

Comment: @Raymond I believe my answer should still be relevant, you haven't bound `_renderHeader` wherever you're using it. Can you check this?

Comment: It worked. Thank you. But shouldn't `this` be bound since I already have the accordion class within a listview?

Comment: @Raymond Without seeing your code I can't say for sure, but generally, if you're passing a function to a view in a fashion similar to what you see above, then the view is likely going to use that as a callback and as a result, `this` is going to be attached to a different object.

Answer (score 0):

React callbacks on elements need to be **bound** for `this` to work.

Try adding the following function to your class:

```
onOpacityClick() {
    NavigationActions.movie_grid({dataID: sectionID});
    this.toggleDrawer();
}
```

Try replacing your first return to this:

```
   return(
     <View>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onOpacityClick.bind(this)}>
         <Text style={{color: "#000", padding: 15}}>{section.title.replace(/[0-9]|,/g, '')}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   )
```